# sqlによる日付の集計について

Tags: sql, postgresql

当方postgresqlを使っています。
A(日付,月,数量),B(開始日,終了日)という2つのテーブルを使ったSQLで
"select sum(数量) as　合計 group by 月"という式を、
開始日終了日の間の数量は除外するようにしたいのですが、
どうすればいいでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。以下のSQLでうまくいきました。

```
select 月,sum(数量) as 合計 from A where not exists (select * from B where a.日付 between b.開始日 and b.終了日)  group by 月
```